# GPU card not working on google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I ve a Google compute Engine VM:

n1-standard-2

- 2vCPU,
- 7.5 GO RAM
- NVidia Tesla P100 GPU
- Windows Server 2019

But the NVidia GPU card is not working with the server. When I go to the devices manager Windows I see the following error message:

> This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use. (Code
>   12)
>
> If you want to use this device, you will need to disable one of the
>   other devices on this system.

I'installed the last NVidia driver but it still doesn't work.

Do you have an idea to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Maxime

Comment: I believe the P100 isn't supporting Windows Server 2019 as per this [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/grid/7.0/grid-vgpu-release-notes-microsoft-windows-server/index.html#abstract)

Comment: Hi, have you managed to solve the issue in the end?
Have you tried to give the machine more RAM, for ex. 16GB?

Answer (score -2):

I've tried to reproduce your scenario, and in my Windows Server 2019 with same specs the driver for Nvidia Tesla P100 is detected without errors.

Could you try to uninstall the current driver for the GPU and to install the [latest version](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/144597/en-us) for NVidia Tesla P100.